# VBA scrape website to get all artist names and albums?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Ok, I`m totally clueless about what I need to do regarding this topic...

Here is code. I took first some links from website, and then I should follow link by link and take some data from that website...

```
Sheets("LINKS TEMP").Activate

Dim httpObject As Object
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Dim links As Variant
Dim l As Variant

With httpObject
    .Open "GET", "http://www.smoothjazz.com/charts/", False
    .Send
    Do Until httpObject.ReadyState = 4
    Loop
    doc.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    Set links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    I = 1
    For Each l In links
        Sheets("LINKS TEMP").Cells(I, 2).Value = l.href
        I = I + 1
    Next l
End With

Sheets("LINKS TEMP").Activate
lrLINKS = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
copyLINKS = 1
For deleteLINKS = 1 To lrLINKS
If Cells(deleteLINKS, 2).Value Like "*votesbytrack*" Then GoTo copyLOOP
GoTo nextLOOP
copyLOOP:
Cells(deleteLINKS, 2).Copy
Cells(copyLINKS, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
copyLINKS = copyLINKS + 1
nextLOOP:
Next deleteLINKS
LRlinks2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For formatLINKS = 1 To LRlinks2
Cells(formatLINKS, 1).Value = "http://smoothjazz.com/charts/" & 
Right(Cells(formatLINKS, 1), Len(Cells(formatLINKS, 1)) - 6)
nextLINK = Sheets("LINKS TEMP").Cells(formatLINKS, 1).Text
Range("B:B").ClearContents

With httpObject
    .Open "GET", Sheets("LINKS TEMP").Cells(formatLINKS, 1).Text, False
    .Send
    Do Until httpObject.ReadyState = 4
    Loop
    doc.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    Set elem = doc.getElementsByClassName("trackingalbumname")
    x = 1
    For Each l In elem
        Sheets("HEADER TEMP").Cells(x, 1).Value = l.span
        x = x + 1
    Next l
End With

Next formatLINKS
```

Why is it breaking in part with GetElementsByClassName?

Here is HTML:

```html
<div class='content'>


 
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table width="601" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="trackingtitle">
   
     <span class="trackingartistname">NATHAN EAST<br/></span>
     <span class="trackingalbumname">Reverence <br/></span>
```

It is just one artist/album, but it needs to run trough entire HTML and find them all!

What do I need to do...Except to start learning hard?!

Comment: Ok.. so what's the question? See [ask] for tips.

Comment: How to get artist name and album?

Comment: Like Nathan East and Reverence in this case.

Comment: I want on this link (Sheets("LINKS TEMP").Cells(formatLINKS, 1).Text) to find and return artist name and album name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use the InternetExplorer.Application instead of MSXML2.XMLHTTP. And I hear that the htmlfile was deprecated from IE 11 and will no longer work. As for the getelementsbyclassname. It should be .document.getelementsbyclassname. Also, not sure if you wanted "span" or the attributes. I used tagname as a demo. To get the value of the artist, swap tagname for innertext or innerhtml. You can observe the object attributes in the locals windows and step through the code. Look for the attribute's value that matches the data that you are trying to **scrape**.

```
Sheets("LINKS TEMP").Activate
 Dim httpObject As Object
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 Dim doc As Object
 ' Set doc = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 Dim links As Variant
 Dim l As Variant

 With httpObject
   .navigate "http://www.smoothjazz.com/charts/"
   Do Until httpObject.ReadyState = 4
     DoEvents
   Loop
   .Visible = True
End With

Set doc = httpObject
  Set elem = doc.document.getElementsByClassName("first")
  x = 1
 For Each l In elem
    Sheets("HEADER TEMP").Cells(x, 1).Value = l.tagname
    x = x + 1
 Next l
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, this way I`m getting only tagnames. A, LI, A, A, LI...and so on. First part of my original code works. It goes on Smoothjazz.com/charts and grab all links I need from there (late I filter those for only I actually need). Second part of code (for scraping) should be command where each link (scraped, formated and stashed in LINKS TEMP) is followed in same way and certain information from each link scraped back to excel (like artist name and album name)

Comment: I`ve paste HTML code for second part of scraping where we need to follow links from my list and scrap data from them (part of data in HTML code I pasted in this post)

Comment: Update! Your comment helped me alot as it pointed me in right direction what I need to change and how this whole thing works!